# My Lamp does not glow as I want. The lamp does not have a material properties section

Tags: lighting

I am trying to create a neuron with glowing light pulses. I succeeded in animating my lamp  on the neuron branche. However, the light it emits is not strong no matter how much I increase intensity. I think it is not an intensity problem but I am not using the right settings. I have just started working on Blender 2.9  5 days ago. I checked many similar questions talking about cycles (which I don't know what is it) but I did not succeed to realize it on my model. I found also one video on youtube but it was without sound and skipped this precise step. If someone knows how to help in detailed steps I would be so grateful.

[image]

---

I tried your suggestion but nothing changes [image]

Comment: if you want your lamp to glow as in the second picture, you can use the Bloom option in Eevee. Cycles and Eevee are the 2 render engines of Blender, you can choose the one or the other in the Properties panel > Render > Render Engine. The Bloom option is in the same panel

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing changes !

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: I am using Eevee

Answer (score 0):

[image: Render Properties when eevee selected]

I'm using Blender 2.9.1.0. Bloom is found under Render Properties when *EEVEE* is selected but not when Cycles is selected.